# Efficiently comparing two ~100M row data sets in Python?

Tags: python, dataset, cython

Attempting to compare two ~100M row HDF5 datasets. The first dataset is the Master and the second is the result of the master being mapped and run thorough a cluster to discern a specific result for each row.

I need to validate that all the intended rows from the master are present, remove any duplicates and create a list of any missing rows that need to be computed. Hash values would be generated from the common elements between the two datasets. I realize though it wouldn't likely be practical to loop through them row by row with native Python.

Such being the case what would be a more efficient means of running this task? Do you try to code something in Cython to offset the issue with Python loop speed or is there a "better" way ?

Comment: Try numpy array comparison? Numpy is extremely fast.

Comment: How can you tell whether a row in the output matches a row in the input?  Is there a primary key in each row?  Are you using PyTables or h5py?  What is the size of the primary keys, and how much memory do you have available?

Comment: I don't think the task you describe is CPU-bound.  It's almost certainly IO-bound, so it's probably completely immaterial whether you write it in Python or any other language.